# In any binary matrix is there any efficient way to confirm one 0 in one row and rest of item is 1 in matlab?

Tags: math, matrix, binary, matlab

for example

```
A=[0 0 0;
   1 1 1;
   1 0 0; 
   1 1 0; 
   0 0 1];
```

After applying function

```
A=[1 1 0;
   1 1 0;
   1 1 0; 
   1 0 1];
```

One row one zero and rest of them are one. if all are one put one zero randomly.  if more than one zero is find take random one and convert all zeros into one.

Comment: I don't understand how you go from the first array to the second array.  Please edit the text of your question -- the title is already too long and doesn't actually explain matters well.

Comment: I don't get it neither....

Comment: it''s it possible without for loop vai matlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are asking is a way to detect that each row contains a single zero, with the remaining row elements all equal to 1, then you can try this. If your matrix to be tested is an `m` x `n` matrix `A` then

```
 sum(A == 1,2)
```

should result in a `(m x 1)` matrix with all elements equal to `n-1`. Similarly, if every row of `A` has just one zero, then

```
sum(A == 0,2)
```

should return a `(m x 1)` matrix with elements all equal to 1. The kind of matrix you require should then satisfy

```
sum(sum(A == 1,2) == (n-1)) = m
```

and

```
sum(sum(A == 0,2) == (n-1)) = m
```

I am not sure if this is what you are actually asking as your question is quite unclear, but this does actually do what the question **title** itself is asking (depending on your definition of efficient of course).